# MPMoviePlayerController crashing and not playing movie

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to play a movie using MPMoviePlayerController. When I call play method, i am getting following crash.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <MPAVController 0x15786750> for the key path "currentItem" from <MPAVPlaylistManager 0x15787750> because it is not registered as an observer.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f148ed3 0x391716c7 0x2f148e15 0x2fa7227f 0x2fa71ca7 0x30393977 0x3038d5ef 0x303889d5 0x3036a36b 0x3036c6bb 0x2f10ae79 0x2f07eb81 0x2fa463c5 0x2fa4acc7 0x303ef943 0x39672103 0x396720ef 0x396749a9 0x2f1135b9 0x2f111e85 0x2f07c541 0x2f07c323 0x33b10343 0x316957b5 0x3a719 0x3a6a0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am not sure whats happening, as I dont have setup any KVO observer for `currentItem` from `MPAVPlaylistManager` which is an internal class.

anybody else got this issue?

Comment: Paste code about what you tried?

Comment: THe issues you are seeing here are triggered by problems of your code, even if your code doesnt use KVO etc - the player does internally. It appears to be an incorrect initilizing of the player or a premature tear down. WIthout seeing your code, we will hardly be able to help any further.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is massing with MPMoviePlayerController instance that was created. I had the same issue a while back and As far as i can think of there can be two things 1. You are changing contentURL of the instance that you have created while playing a video 2.you are incorrectly releasing the instance of MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue, the problem was related to iOS7 (that is under NDA at the moment). AVPlayer behaviour is changed if the player is started from a secondary thread. the player object will be nil. fixed my issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you please share how you have solved the issue as I am running player on the main thread only.

Comment: The code is in NDA. The fix should be released for the community, that you seem to be using quite a lot.